# qmake does not add widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, qtwidgets

i have a simple program.  my program is:

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QLabel>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int rc ; 
    QApplication app(argc, argv);  
     QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello Qt!");
    label->show();
     rc = app.exec();
     return(rc) ;
}
```

i want to compile and build this code in command line.
i have installed qt and mingw.

first my command is:

```
  qmake -project
```

then i give  this command.

```
  qmake
```

then qmake creates .pro file which is:

```
 TEMPLATE = app
 TARGET = HELLO
 INCLUDEPATH += .

 # Input
 SOURCES += hello.cpp
```

i think this file must inclue ' QT += widgets' but it doesnt. i dont know why.
finally, i call mingw make

and it gives error.

when i add .pro file  QT += widgets then call mingw-make, it works and creates .exe file.

then my question is that, why qmake automatically add  `QT += widgets` , how can i do this? i dont want to add manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can i do this? i dont want to add manually.

You can do the following things:

1) You could use QtCreator and select the widget based application.

2) qmake -project "QT += widgets"

but nothing more. QMake is not a C++ code project parser.

Also, note that you could use `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):QT+=widgets` to be compatible with Qt 4 if that matters for you since the widgets were in the gui module for Qt 4 and core and gui are added by default. They were put into their own widgets module in Qt 5.

Comment: is there anyway to do this doing `qmake -project`  like `qmake -project ADD QT bla bla` .

Comment: @legelstein: yes, and already mentioned in my reply. You probably have not updated. :)

Comment: thank you for good answer,now i have another problem, when i try to run .exe , it gives Qt5Core.dll error, but when i open this project in qt-creator it doesnt gives any error, why i couldnt run this .exe

Answer (score 1):

if you are a linux user, you could make a little bash script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "-project" ]; then
 qmake $@ "QT += widgets gui"
else  
 qmake $@
fi
```

(following the point 2 of lpapp) and place it in /usr/bin directory.. if you want, you could rename qmake to something like qmake_old, rename the script as "qmake" and then

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "-project" ]; then
 qmake_old $@ "QT += widgets gui"
else
 qmake_old $@
fi
```

so you can normally call qmake ad it does automatically what you want
(NB don't forget chmod +x )
tested on ubuntu 14.04