# Qt Hello World Tutorial doesn't work

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I am trying to run a hello world program and the tutorials don't work for me.

I am guessing that it's got something to do with `qt4 <-> qt5` and `linux <-> windows` confusion.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit. I did a `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and a `sudo apt-get install qt5-default`.

This is the code in my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Linux is wonderful", 0);
    app.setMainWidget(label);
    label->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I run these commands:

```
qmake -project
qmake test.pro (for some reason it's not "main.pro")
make
```

Here is the generated .pro file:

```
###################################################################### 
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) So. Okt. 25 15:51:35 2015 
###################################################################### 
TEMPLATE = app 
TARGET = test 
INCLUDEPATH += . 
# Input 
SOURCES += mymain.cpp
```

And then I get `QApplication: No such file or directory`. Why?

Comment: .pro file name is typically  name of directory, that's why it is test.pro, btw.

Comment: what is `test.pro`? and why you are using `-project`

Comment: ######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) So. Okt. 25 15:51:35 2015
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += mymain.cpp

Comment: I use "-project" because according to the tutorials it seems to be the way to do it? First qmake -project, then qmake the .pro file, then make, then ./executable ... or not?

Comment: `QT += widgets` is not added in your project source file. See @hyde answer.

Comment: @user3182532 I edited my answer to explain a bit about `qmake -project` and how to use it. Also, you should *edit* the question to add stuff like you now posted as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the necessary module from .pro file. Apparently `qmake -project` does not add that by default (makes sense, since not all Qt apps are widget applications). So check for and add this:

```
QT += widgets
```

This is because Qt5 has widgets in a separate module (Qt4 had them in *gui*), and `QApplication` is part of that, as shown by [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) too. The two modules which qmake adds automatically (and you have to remove if you don't want them) are *core* and *gui* (documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt)), others you have to add to .pro explicitly.

---

Some notes: You generally run `qmake -project` only once to create initial .pro file. Then you need to edit it by hand, and don't want it to be overwritten! Then you never edit Makefiles by hand, instead you regenerate them by running `qmake` after editing the .pro file.

Comment: Hi hyde, what do you mean by "add"? Add where? In the .pro file or the makefile? And where exactly in the files?

Comment: @user3182532, add it to  the project source file. You didn't show your project file

Comment: Oh and: Actually this should not be the problem. I have installed the package "qt5-default" so there's no way I have a qt4 .pro file!

Comment: Yes it is a problem. If you want to let Qt take care of `.pro` then you just type `qmake`. It will automatically generate the Makefile for you however if you want to customize the project file, then you need to show your `.pro` otherwise it is hard to tell.

Comment: Oh that works!? In my history I can see that I did "sudo apt-get install qt5-default". Not "qt4-default". When I type "qmake --version" it tells me that I have qmake version 3.0 and QT version 5.2.1, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @user3182532, by default, the core and gui are added without specifying them in the project source file however if you are using any widget, then you have to add them as  hyde added in the answer.

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of qmake was that it automatically generates the project file for your .cpp file? So that you do not need to type every line yourself? Why wouldn't it generate the line "QT += widgets"? EDIT: Found a thread where someone else is wondering about the exact same thing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711592/qmake-does-not-add-widgets). Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @user3182532, this is why you need to read the documentation and you are welcome.

Comment: @user3182532 The purpose of *qmake* is to generate the Makefiles. `qmake -project` is just for convenience, to get a project started. For example I practically always create new projects with Qt Creator, so I for one never use `qmake -project`.

Comment: @user3182532 Just to let you know. I had a bit of wrong info about the Ubuntu packages in the answer, edited. The package you need is `qtbase5-dev`, and that seems to be installed when you install `qt5-default`, so that should be in order.